# Does Chrome on Linux use its own font subpixel smoothing settings?

Tags: chrome, fonts, display-settings

I am using an LCD TV as my monitor. In Mate settings I can change the subpixel order to BGR to get a better subpixel smoothing. However, I notice that some applications are using their own subpixel smoothing (e.g., IntelliJ, which has its own setting and cannot choose the subpixel order, so I changed it to grayscale smoothing).

I wonder if Chrome is using its own subpixel smoothing, since some elements are showing me some rainbow effect on the edge of the fonts, e.g., the address bar shown in the screenshot. If it IS using its own settings, how to configure it?

[image]